# difference between MAP_PRIVATE and MAP_SHARED in mmap for threads

Tags: c, pthreads, mmap

The content of file 'hello' is `hello`.

```
$ od -tx1 -tc hello 
0000000 68 65 6c 6c 6f 0a
          h   e   l   l   o  \n
0000006
```

Below is my code to make some changes to the file 'hello'.

```
static void *task();

int main(void)
{
    int *p;
    pthread_t Thread;
    int fd = open("hello", O_RDWR);
    if (fd < 0) {
        perror("open hello");
        exit(1);
    }
    p = mmap(NULL, 6, PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE, fd, 0);
    if (p == MAP_FAILED) {
        perror("mmap");
        exit(1);
    }
    close(fd);
    pthread_create(&Thread, NULL, &task, p)
    printf("Help");
    pthread_join(Thread, 0);
    munmap(p, 6);
    return 0;
}

static void * task(int *r)
{
 r[0] = 0x30313233;
}
```

The code above I used `MAP_PRIVATE`, and it seems that the child thread does not work.
If I change `MAP_PRIVATE` to `MAP_SHARED`, I see it makes the difference I expect.

```
$ od -tx1 -tc hello
 0000000 33 32 31 30 6f 0a
           3   2   1   0   o  \n
 0000006
```

But I have no idea how it happens.

Comment: `man mmap: MAP_PRIVATE Create a private copy-on-write mapping.  Updates to the mapping [...] are  not carried through to the underlying file.`. Also, you're violating strict aliasing.

Comment: @EOF Thanks for your reply. I have realized my problem...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This has nothing to do with threads, you would have the same result if you did the modification in the main thread. The whole point of `MAP_PRIVATE` is not to propagate the modification to the underlying object (in this case, the file). This is described in [the manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html):

> `MAP_PRIVATE` - Create a private copy-on-write mapping.  Updates to
>   the mapping are not visible to other processes mapping the same file,
>   and are not carried through to the underlying file.  It is unspecified
>   whether changes made to the file after the `mmap()` call are visible
>   in the mapped region.

In other words, `MAP_PRIVATE` gets you a region of memory for the private use of your process (in all its threads) and the forked subprocesses, which will not be written anywhere. You can think of it as an alternative to `malloc()`.

Comment: How stupid I am...Thanks for your time and reply anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Always a good idea to read the [manual](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mmap) as it tells you precisely why.

> MAP_SHARED
>
> Share this mapping. Updates to the mapping are visible to other processes that map this file, **and are carried through to the
>   underlying file**. The file may not actually be updated until msync(2)
>   or munmap() is called.
>
> MAP_PRIVATE
>
> Create a private copy-on-write mapping. Updates to the mapping are not visible to other processes mapping the same file, **and are not
>   carried through to the underlying file**.